# URL for Salesforce page with no header or sidebar, List view buttons are not working

Tags: apex, visualforce, url, sidebar, header

I am trying to develop a page wizard which helps our users "Complete multiple interactions" (create multiple records) on one page.
In order to accomplish this, I have created the URLS for the records which I need to create, and appended them to with the `isdtp=vw` parameter to make them render without sidebar or header, and in aloha theme.
I have noticed that none of my related list buttons work on the pages that are displayed.
Is there any way to create a URL for a page that without header and sidebar, but retains related list functionality?

Example:

```
 private list<SelectOption> GetHospitalizationInteractions(){
    List<Hospitalization__c> IncompleteHospitalizations = [SELECT ID, Intervention_Status__c, Patient_Name__c
                                                           FROM Hospitalization__c
                                                           WHERE (Intervention_Status__c!= 'Complete' AND Intervention_Status__c!= 'Declined Consult')
                                                           AND Patient_Name__c =: Account.id
                                                           AND  Discharge_Date__c= LAST_N_DAYS:180 ];
    List<SelectOption> Returnlist = new list<SelectOption>();
    for (Hospitalization__c Hosp : IncompleteHospitalizations){
        String URL = '/'+ Hosp.id + '/e?retURL=' + Hosp.Id+ '&isdtp=vw&ent=Hospitalization__c';
        Returnlist.add(New SelectOption(URL, 'Incomplete Hospitalization Consult'));
    }

    return returnlist;
}
```

Those URLs are stored in a map which is called `URLtoTitle` which gets populated in the `MoveToCompletionPage` Method.

They are then repeated over in an `apex:repeat` tag in the pageblock with `ID="DisplayBlock"` and `title="Please complete the following interactions"` to iframe their destination.

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Please complete the following interactions" id="Displayblock"  rendered="{!ShowCompletionPage}">

        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandbutton action="{!Cancel}" value="Exit" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:repeat value="{!URLtoTitle}" var="URL"> 
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!URLtoTitle[URL]}" columns="1" > 
                <apex:iframe src="{!URL}" frameborder="true" scrolling="true" title="Iframe" id="frame" height="400px"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:repeat> 

    </apex:pageBlock>
```

Here is a screenshot of the button that is lacking functionality.

[image: Iframed detail page with non functioning list view buttons]

Please note that I have also tried changing the URL tag to `idstp=mn` and this works, but does not display the page in aloha, and it looks pretty bad.

Can you please help me figure out a way to create URLs for records which do not display the sidebar or header, yet retain the related list button functionality?